# Prove that if a subgroup $H$ of a finite cyclic group $G=\langle a \rangle $ of order $n$ is generated by $a^m$, then $m$ is a divisor of $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Prove that if a subgroup $H$ of a finite cyclic group $G=\langle a
>  \rangle $ of order $n$ is generated by $a^m$, then $m$ is a divisor of
>   $n$.

It can be easily shown that $m$ is the least positive integer such that $H=\langle a^m\rangle$. But I stuck to show that $m\mid n$.   If $o(a^m)=r$, then $a^{mr}=e\implies n\mid mr$ (since $o(a)=n$). I think my approaches going on wrong. How can prove that $m\mid n$?

Comment: Must $H$ be a non-trivial subgroup? For $\mathbb Z_{10}$ itself is generated by $a^3$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel you are right.

Comment: I doubt if the statement is true. For instance, if we take $G = \langle a \rangle$ and order $p$ (a prime) , then $G = \{e,a,a^2,a^3,...,a^{p-1} \}$ and take $H = \langle a^k \rangle, 2\le k \le p-1$. Then, we have  a subgroup and $k\nmid p$. 
Someone Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Will it not? I am taking the cyclic subgroup generated by an element of the group itself. But I guess that won't work for you because the example I gave fits in the category of what @ParclyTaxel gave. In my example also, the subgroup becomes the whole group.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true, even for proper subgroups.  $\langle 8 \rangle \subsetneq \Bbb Z / 12 \Bbb Z$ but $8 \not | 12$.  The best you can hope for is $(m, n) \gt 1.$

Comment: $H=<a^m>$, $m$ is the least positive integer. If $n=mq+r$ for some integers $q,r(0\leq r<m)$. Then $a^r=a^{-mq}\in H$. Minimality of $m$ forces $r=0$ and hence $m\mid n$. Is it correct? @RobertShore

Comment: @MKS So the proper statement is that if $H \subsetneq G$, then $\exists m$ such that $m|n$ and $H = \langle a^m \rangle$.  And yes your completion of the proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That statement is wrong, as Robert Shore's answer shows. What is true is that if $a^m$ generates a subgroup $H$ of $G=\{1,a,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1}\}$, then the order of this subgroup must divide the order of the group $G$ (i.e. $|H|$ divides $n$). But in this case we do not even need that $G$ is cyclic--the order of every subgroup of any group always has order dividing the order of the group. This fact is known as Lagrange's Theorem.